# I can't use c++ format header

Tags: c++

Hi I'm taking basic c++ test
the answer is required  so I write #include  but error is happened
error message is that header is not existed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string str = format("{}+{}+{}", 16, 14, 30);
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check to make sure your implementation has support for it?

Answer (score 0):

`<format>` is C++ 20 feature. You should check your test site's C++ version

Answer (score 0):

As of now, no compiler supports `<format>`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:cpp/compiler_support/20).

Alternatively, you can use  [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)